# whoami /priv for another user

Tags: windows, scripting

Is there a way to see the privileges for any (local or domain) user in Windows ?
`whoami /priv` works for the current user.
Not clear from the docs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299(v=ws.11).aspx
Need to check this for other users (example: service account for SQL Server). And use what's included in Windows, not rely on Sysinternals tools that might not be installed on all servers. There also a complex way of doing it with secedit, not happy about it as it involves writing a result file to disk. Powershell maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

[This has been asked & answered on sister-site superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1065000/how-to-list-windows-privileges-for-any-user). The suggestion was to use [AccessChk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922) which is EXE provided by Microsoft (when they purchased sysinternals)